# Text or annotation in a plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Since I don't understand how notations work, I just need to add in a plot the mean value and add a label to write the point. I added the white star

```
scatter(azimuth,elevation,'r'),'filled';
hold on;
plot(az_mean,el_mean,'wp'); hold on;
```

then I added the label with

```
str = {az1_mean,el1_mean};
text (az1_mean,el1_mean,str);
```

but the two values are in two different lines. How can I get this format `(az1_mean,el1_mean)`?

```
x = linspace(0,3*pi,200);
y = cos(x) + rand(1,200);  
y_mean = mean(y); x_mean = mean(x)    
h1 = figure(1);
scatter(x,y)
xlabel('Azimuth); ylabel('Elevati');
hold on;
plot(x_mean,y_mean,'wp'); hold on;
str = {x_mean,y_mean};
text (x_mean,y_mean,str);
hold off;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `text` function, if you give the text argument as a cell array, the new row/column in the cell array will be considered as a new line for text. Take a look at [*this example*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html#busohq7-1).

To fix your problem, just explicitly convert both of `x_mean` and `y_mean` into character arrays and concatenate them with brackets outside and a comma in between i.e

```
text(x_mean, y_mean, ['(', num2str(x_mean), ', ', num2str(y_mean), ')']);
```

[image: output]

By the way, there is no need of multiple `hold on`s. A single `hold on` will keep holding on unless you `hold off`.